# Call a remote rest api for each kafka message consumed

Tags: apache-kafka

I am reading a file (line by line) in kafka producer and sending each record(i.e per line) across the stream and kafka consumer is receiving this record.Further i need to send it to rest api service from kafka consumer to do some processing and my response would be send to some other topic and so on.
I am not sure how can we do it using producer -consumer kafka api?
Need help

Comment: For future posts, please share your code as a [mcve]. If you already had a consumer, then seems like you're asking for just how you can make an HTTP request, which is unrelated to how you actually got the data you want to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple. This is how you need to develop a Spring Boot Application with KAFKA Consumer Client that integrates with any backend REST API.

1. A Class to instatiate a consumer object

```
package x.x.x.x.x.

@Service

public class KAFKAConsumer implements Runnable{

    public void run(String topicName) {
        try {
            Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>();
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        LOGGER.debug("Polling topic for new events...");
                        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
                        for (TopicPartition partition : consumerRecords.partitions()) {
                            List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = consumerRecords.records(partition);
                            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : partitionRecords) {

                                // Calling REST API for each record

                                invokeRestAPIClass(Parameters....)

                                try {
                                    consumer.commitSync();
                                } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SerializationException e1) {
                        continue;
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            } finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

2. A class to define REST API Template

You can this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/ as a reference to construct a REST API template and include invokeRestAPIClass(Parameters....), to map your request throuhg POJO Classes based on the REST API request and response structure.

3. Implementing a Spring Boot Startup main class

```
package x.x.x.x.x.

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "x.x.x.x.x")

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy

public class SpringBootStartup implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Inject
    private KAFKAConsumer consumer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args){
        try {
            Thread springBootThread = new Thread(consumer);
            springBootThread.start();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootStartup.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi ChristDist,Thanks for the quick response.one more question is how will my producer look like in this case?  As i am reading a file i.e csv or excel in the producer end and sending it through kafkatemplate method send -- something similar tho this link --- https://www.netsurfingzone.com/kafka/spring-boot-kafka-producer-and-consumer-example-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: I usually recommend people to refer https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example. Doesn't matter though. Also, reading a .csv or excel, you can write a plain java code to poll a .csv or .xls and map it into Java objects through POJO classes and convert it into KAFKA Producer Record. For that you need to define a Event Schema, it can be either AVRO or JSON. So the output of Request mapping through POJO and Schema should be identical in terms of Fields. Note: If you are after a KAFKA Solution instead, then you have to use one of the available KAFKA Connectors to do the job.

Comment: I am totally new to kafka ..so how can we define a event schema in spring boot kafka application ?

Comment: @TestAdmin Spring doesn't help with schemas. If you want to define JSON/Avro/Protobuf schemas for the records, then that's done outside of Kafka methods

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you share some example with me ? .. that would be helpful

Comment: @TestAdmin Confluent blog is a great resource https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-avro-in-spring-boot-application-tutorial/

Comment: Wont it be a bottle neck when we call the api for each event in kafka ? Like it will behave in sync right ?